# Converting a string into multiple words removing special characters

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I  need to convert a given string in to multiple words in PLPGSQL, have tried regrex and substr but we are not getting the desired results.
eg

1. string ABC's will be divided into two words ABC and ABCS
   variable1= ABC's will be divided into variable2=ABC variable3=ABCS
2. A.B.C will become ABC
   variable1=A.B.C will become variable 2 =ABC
3. single letter separated with spaces become single word ( A B C) becomes ABC
   variable1=A B C will become variable 2 =ABC
4. Single letter words are eliminated by adding them to next word
   eg A B DEF will become AB DEF
   variable1=A B DEF will become variable 2 =AB variable3= DEF
5. words containing - would become three words
   eg ABC-DEF will become ABC DEF ABCDEF
   variable1=ABC-DEF will become variable 2 =ABC variable3= DEF variable4= ABCDEF

Any response would really be appreciated.

Comment: yes . is not needed , have removed it

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** I misread the question and thought you wanted to know how to simply remove special characters (not completely answering your question but it should give you a head start).

I don't know if this completely answers your question, but it should work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function "removeSpecialCharacters"(input text) 
RETURNS text as $$
DECLARE
   output text;
BEGIN
   output := (select regexp_replace(input, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g'));
   RETURN output;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How to use?

```
select "removeSpecialCharacters"(input);
```

Example

```
select "removeSpecialCharacters"('A.B.C');
```

Produces 'ABC' output